# Adding dynamic array to the end of a static array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got the following code which is within a `sql` loop to determine how many rows i output onto a spreadsheet. Basically without pasting the full thing as it's quite a lengthy statement, the top `SQL` statement will return 60 rows, which will contain the variables I enter into the original `$data1` array.

```
$stmt2= $mysqV1->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT master_recipe, recipe, matl_id, comp_length, comp_width, comp_tck from components where recipe > 0 and matl_id > 0 order BY  CAST(recipe AS UNSIGNED) ASC" );

foreach ($result2 as $key2=>$value2)
  {
 $data1[]=(array("Master Recipe"=>$master_recipe,"Recipe"=>$recipe,"Recipe Name"=>$recipe_name,"Material"=>$material,"Length"=>$comp_length,"Width"=>$comp_width,"Thickness"=>$comp_tck));
  }
```

I then have a further nested loop (inside the original `$result2` loop) which will determine how many elements i add to that array, as the value will change from record to record. I have tried to declare an array then use array push and array merge but neither of them seem to do what i want.

```
$temp7 = array($master_recipe);
$stmt7= $mysqV1->prepare("Select * from machine where master_recipe = ? order by route_header_id asc" );
$stmt7->execute($temp7);
$result7=$stmt7->fetchAll();
foreach ($result7 as $key7=>$value7)
{
    $station_id = $value7['route_header_id'];
    $time_taken = $value7['time_hrs'];
    $a[] = (array("StationID"=>$time_taken));
    array_push($data1,$a);
}
```

So what I would like this to do is add the contents of `$a` to the end of `$data1` to give me 1 array value which then prints out to my spreadsheet(the print part is already working for the `$data1` array) but it's not adding the $a to it.

Final result I would like to end up something like this for the value in `$data1`

```
$data1[]=(array("Master Recipe"=>$master_recipe,"Recipe"=>$recipe,"Recipe Name"=>$recipe_name,"Material"=>$material,"Length"=>$comp_length,"Width"=>$comp_width,"Thickness"=>$comp_tck,"$station_id1"=>$time_taken,"$station_id2"=>$time_taken2,"$station_id3"=>$time_taken3));
```

Comment: You shouldn't be pushing `$a` every time through the loop, since each one contains the values that were pushed the previous time.

Comment: Why aren't you using `$station_id`? Did you mean to write `array($station_id => $time_taken)`?

Comment: Or maybe `$a[$station_id] = $time_taken`?

Comment: Can you show what you want the final result to look like?

Comment: @Barmar yes sorry i meant that.

Comment: final result is hard as it gets output to a spreadsheet, but basically, i want data1 to have all of those values above, then also the dynamic values in $a...

so something like 

`$data1[]=(array("Master Recipe"=>$master_recipe,"Recipe"=>$recipe,"Recipe Name"=>$recipe_name,"Material"=>$material,"Length"=>$comp_length,"Width"=>$comp_width,"Thickness"=>$comp_tck,"$station_id1"=>$time_taken,"$station_id2"=>$time_taken2,"$station_id3"=>$time_taken3));`

Comment: Please put it in the question so you can format it readably.

Comment: Assigning to `$data1[]` means to push a new element into the `$data1` array. So are you adding this as a new element or updating the existing element?

Comment: Is `$data1` supposed to be a 1-dimensional or 2-dimensional array? Assigning an array to `$data1[]` makes it 2-dimensional.

Comment: updating the existing element if possible, makes it easier to output it to the spreadsheet in the correct format if it is all part of one array

Comment: But which element should it update? You're adding a new row every time you assign to `$data1[]`. Is this part of another loop that's adding that row, so you want to include this in the row?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196540/discussion-between-macca424-and-barmar).

Comment: I'm guessing you want to change the initial "static" array assigned from `$data1[] = (array...` to `$data1 = array(` (remove the `[]`). Then add your new data to it like `$data1[$station_id] = $time_taken;` (get rid of the `$a` array and the `array_push` stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Put the row that you're adding to `$data1` in the `$a` variable, then you can add new elements to that row before you push it into `$data1`.

```
foreach ($result2 as $value2) {
    $master_recipe = $value2['master_recipe'];
    $recipe = $value2['recipe'];
    ...
    $a = array("Master Recipe"=>$master_recipe,"Recipe"=>$recipe,"Recipe Name"=>$recipe_name,"Material"=>$material,"Length"=>$comp_length,"Width"=>$comp_width,"Thickness"=>$comp_tck);
    $temp7 = array($master_recipe);
    $stmt7= $mysqV1->prepare("Select route_header_id, time_hrs from machine where master_recipe = ? order by route_header_id asc" );
    $stmt7->execute($temp7);
    while ($value7 = $stmt7->fetch())
    {
        $station_id = $value7['route_header_id'];
        $time_taken = $value7['time_hrs'];
        $a[$station_id] = $time_taken;
    }
    $data1[] = $a;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look right. You are setting `$row` in the loop but then don't use it?

Comment: Oops, I switched from `$row` to `$a` and missed one of the edits.

Comment: Perfect, tested this and it does exactly what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What if you change your initial set of `$data1` to this:

```php
$data1= array(
    "Master Recipe"=>$master_recipe,
    "Recipe"=>$recipe,
    "Recipe Nme"=>$recipe_name,
    "Material"=>$material,
    "Length"=>$comp_length,
    "Width"=>$comp_width,
    "Thickness"=>$comp_tck
);
```

then, in your loop..

```php
foreach ($result7 as $key7=>$value7)
{
    $station_id = $value7['route_header_id'];
    $time_taken = $value7['time_hrs'];
    $data1[$station_id] = $time_taken;
}
```

Comment: In chat he explained that `$data1` is supposed to be a 2-dimensional array, not one row.

Comment: His "final result" looks like he wants $data to be an array of a single array?

Comment: That would be true if he wrote `$data1 =`, but `$data1[] =` means to push a new row into the 2-d array.

Comment: This is all inside another loop that's processing the result of another query from the master table.

Comment: Ok, got it. You're answer wins! :P

Comment: yes sorry I don't think it was very easy to see this from my original question, I tried to edit this as best I could, my code didn't make it the easiest to format whatever way it's coming out of the editor.